# Is it possible to suppress specific messages from docker logs?

Tags: linux, docker, logging

I have thousands of INFO reaped unknown pid XXXXX in my docker logs when I do a docker logs -f, is there any way to suppress these messages via a regex for these logs?

Example Format [DATE] [TIME] INFO reaped unknown pid XXXX

Answer (score 0):

You could use `grep -v -e '<REGEXP>'`

Example:

```
docker logs <CONTAINER_ID> -f 2>&1 | grep -v -e "2019.*INFO"
```

Comment: Beautiful, thank you, I have <15 rep so I cannot upvote, please someone do

Comment: Happy to help you! You could mark my answer as solution :)